# how to move QLineEdit and QPushButton to next line

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

I have trouble with my code and I can't move *entry2* and *btn2* to the bottom of *entry1* and *btn1* and when trying it cause chaos in my code.
I use PyQt5 to programing. I would be grateful if you guided me through this..

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        V = QtWidgets.QApplication.desktop().screenGeometry()
        h, w, x, y = V.height(), V.width(), 1000, 600
        self.setGeometry(h/4, w/20, x, y)
        self.setFixedSize(x, y)
        self.setWindowTitle('Main Window')
        centralWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.setCentralWidget(centralWidget)
        self.grid = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(centralWidget)
        OpenFile = QtWidgets.QAction('Open', self)
        OpenFile.setShortcut('Ctrl+O')
        OpenFile.setStatusTip('Open Restore File...')
        self.statusBar()
        mainMenu = self.menuBar()
        fileMenu = mainMenu.addMenu('File')
        fileMenu.addAction(OpenFile)
        self.home()

    def home(self):
        self.tools_in_home()
        self.show()

    def tools_in_home(self):
        self.groupBox0 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 1') 
        self.groupBox0.setFixedSize(400, 200)
        hBoxLayout1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        entry1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Enter Value1...')
        entry2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Enter Valu2...')
        hBoxLayout1.addWidget(entry1)
        hBoxLayout1.addWidget(entry2)
        btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit1', self)
        btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit2', self)
        hBoxLayout1.addWidget(btn1)
        hBoxLayout1.addWidget(btn2)
        self.groupBox0.setLayout(hBoxLayout1)
        self.groupBox1 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 2')
        self.groupBox1.setFixedSize(400, 200)
        self.groupBox2 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 3')
        self.groupBox2.setFixedSize(400, 200)
        self.groupBox3 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 4')
        self.groupBox3.setFixedSize(400, 200)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox0, 0, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox1, 2, 0)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox2, 0, 2)
        self.grid.addWidget(self.groupBox3, 2, 2)

def run():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    GUI = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `addWidget()` you must do it in order, that is, first entry1, then btn1, then entry2 and at the end btn2.

```
def tools_in_home(self):
    self.groupBox0 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 1') 
    self.groupBox0.setFixedSize(400, 200)

    hBoxLayout1 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
    entry1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Enter Value1...')
    entry2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Enter Valu2...')
    btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit1')
    btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit2')
    hBoxLayout1.addWidget(entry1)
    hBoxLayout1.addWidget(btn1)
    hBoxLayout1.addWidget(entry2)
    hBoxLayout1.addWidget(btn2)
    self.groupBox0.setLayout(hBoxLayout1)

    # ...
```

**Update:**

If you want to have the structure of a form then use QFormLayout.

```
def tools_in_home(self):
    self.groupBox0 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 1') 
    self.groupBox0.setFixedSize(400, 200)
    lay = QtWidgets.QFormLayout()
    entry1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Enter Value1...')
    entry2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Enter Valu2...')
    btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit1')
    btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit2')
    lay.addRow(entry1, btn1)
    lay.addRow(entry2, btn2)
    self.groupBox0.setLayout(lay)

    # ...
```

[image]

Or QGridLayout:

```
def tools_in_home(self):
    self.groupBox0 = QtWidgets.QGroupBox('Test 1') 
    self.groupBox0.setFixedSize(400, 200)
    lay = QtWidgets.QGridLayout()
    entry1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Enter Value1...')
    entry2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit('Enter Valu2...')
    btn1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit1')
    btn2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Submit2')
    lay.addWidget(entry1, 0, 0)
    lay.addWidget(btn1, 0, 1)
    lay.addWidget(entry2, 1, 0)
    lay.addWidget(btn2, 1, 1)
    self.groupBox0.setLayout(lay)
```

[image]

Comment: thank's, but I want to move _entry2_ and _btn2_ under _entry1_ and _btn1_

Comment: @Nima see my update :-), If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct, if you do not know how to do it then review the [tour], that is the best way to thank.